# MEF Lightweight (System.Composition) Import and Export

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I was wondering if I could get your guidance on the following inquiry.

Let's say I have the following Interface declarations.

```
namespace PlugInBase
{
    public interface IPlugIn
    {
        ISharedInterface SharedInterface { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISharedInterface
    {
        string Message { get; set; }
        IList<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }

        int Num { get; set; }

    }

    public class SharedInterface : ISharedInterface
    {
        private string message;
        private IList<string> listOfStrings;
        private int num;

        public SharedInterface(string message, IList<string> listOfStrings, int num)
        {
            this.message = message;
            this.listOfStrings = listOfStrings;
            this.num = num;
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }
        }

        public IList<string> ListOfStrings
        {
            get { return listOfStrings; }
            set { listOfStrings = value; }
        }

        public int Num
        {
            get { return num; }
            set { num = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following 2 Classes which implement IPlugin and have a reference to ISharedInterface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Composition;
using System.Composition.Convention;
using System.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PlugInA
{
    using PlugInBase;

    public class PlugInAClass : IPlugIn
    {
        private ISharedInterface sharedInterface;

        public PlugInAClass()
        {
            sharedInterface = new SharedInterface("PluginA Message", new List<string>(new string[] { "testString1", "testString2",
            "testString3", "testString4", "testString5" }), 99);
        }

        public ISharedInterface SharedInterface
        {
            get { return sharedInterface; }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Composition;
using System.Composition.Convention;
using System.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PlugInB
{
    using PlugInBase;

    public class PlugInBClass : IPlugIn
    {
        private ISharedInterface sharedInterface;
        public ISharedInterface SharedInterface
        {
            get { return sharedInterface; }
            set { sharedInterface = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, I have a helper class that composes the parts as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Composition;
using System.Composition.Convention;
using System.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;
using PlugInBase;
using PlugInA;
using PlugInB;

namespace MainConsoleApp
{
    public class MEFComposer
    {
        private ContainerConfiguration containerConfiguration = new ContainerConfiguration();
        private IList<Assembly> listOfAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        private ConventionBuilder conventions = new ConventionBuilder();
        private CompositionHost compositionHost = null;
        private IEnumerable<IPlugIn> PlugIns { get; set; }

        public MEFComposer()
        {
            //Get list of assemblies
            listOfAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            listOfAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("PlugInA"));
            listOfAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("PlugInB"));
            listOfAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("PlugInBase"));

            //Conventions to be used to build the container
            conventions.ForType<PlugInAClass>().Export<PlugInAClass>();
            conventions.ForType<PlugInBClass>().Export<PlugInBClass>();
            conventions.ForType<PlugInAClass>().ExportProperty(x => x.SharedInterface);
            conventions.ForType<PlugInBClass>().ImportProperty(x => x.SharedInterface);   

            //Build the container with the list of assemblies and the conventions listed above.
            compositionHost = containerConfiguration.
                WithAssemblies(listOfAssemblies).
                WithDefaultConventions(conventions).
                CreateContainer();

            //Store a reference to the shared interfaces for each plugin
            ISharedInterface plugInASharedInterface = compositionHost.GetExport<PlugInAClass>().SharedInterface;
            ISharedInterface plugInBSharedInterface = compositionHost.GetExport<PlugInBClass>().SharedInterface;

            //Print initial values of the exporter
            PrintSharedInterfaceContent(plugInASharedInterface);

            //Print initial values of the importer
            PrintSharedInterfaceContent(plugInBSharedInterface);

            //Modify the values of the exporter
            plugInASharedInterface.ListOfStrings.Add("testString6");
            plugInASharedInterface.Num++;
            plugInASharedInterface.Message = "This message should have changed";

            //Reprint importer values on the console
            PrintSharedInterfaceContent(plugInBSharedInterface);

            //Why aren't the values of plugInBSharedInterface not reflecting the changes from
            //plugInASharedInterface?
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private void PrintSharedInterfaceContent(ISharedInterface sharedInterface)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IPlugInSharedInterface");
            Console.WriteLine("IPlugInSharedInterface.Message: " + sharedInterface.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("IPlugInSharedInterface.Num: " + sharedInterface.Num);
            Console.WriteLine("IPlugInSharedInterface.List of strings: ");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            foreach (string aString in sharedInterface.ListOfStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aString);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running the code I was expecting that modifying the values of the shared interface on pluginA (the exporter) would be reflected on pluginB (the importer). Unfortunately, the values go unchanged and I cannot seem to figure out how can I use MEF as to be able to change the values of a part's exported property be reflect on another part's imported property.

Thank you very much for all your help,

Answer (score 0):

By default a new instance is returned for each export you define. You need to call Shared() on the export. This marks the part as being shared throughout the entire composition.

[System.Composition.Convention.PartConventionBuilder.Shared()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.composition.convention.partconventionbuilder.shared?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Composition_Convention_PartConventionBuilder_Shared)